# redundant foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a database with the following requirements: There are accounts of different types. They can have different payment plans depending on the type. The whole thing is like a hierarchy with 2 levels. For instance, if the account types were A and B, then the payment plans could be A1, A2, B1, and B2, where Ax would only be valid for account type A and so on.

So far I've got the following setup:
A table **account_types** with **id** and **name**. A table **payment_plans** with **account_type_id** and **id**, both of them are part of the PK. And a table **accounts** with **type_id** and **plan_id**. I guess it's obvious what references what.

My problem is this: **accounts.type_id** is a FK and **accounts.type_id** + **accounts.plan_id** is a composite FK. I don't know if this an optimal solution. The **type_id** is kind of redundant, since it's implicitly defined by the **plan_id**, but only because of the constraints in place in the **payment_plans** table. So what would be best practice here? I could get rid **type_id** entirely, but then it would take another join with the **payment_plans** table just to determine the type of an account.

Thanks for your input in advance. Suggestions involving a completely different structure are also welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have these tables:

- `account_types`:

  - `id`: PK
  - `name`
- `payment_plans`

  - `id`: PK
  - `account_type_id`: FK to `account_types`
- `accounts`

  - whatever columns an account needs
- `accounts2payment_plans`

  - `account_id`: FK to `accounts` and part of PK
  - `payment_plan_id`: FK to `payment_plans` and part of PK

The reasoning behind this is the following:

1. Each account type can have multiple payment plans, therefore the `payment_plans` table needs to reference the `account_type` table. With this reference, the type of a payment plan is defined.
2. Each account can have multiple payment plans, but each payment plan can be used by multiple accounts, that's why the mapping table `accounts2payment_plans` is needed. Through the mapping from account to payment plans all account types of an account are implicitly defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, you misunderstood me in that one account can only have one payment plan assigned to it. There is just multiple choices depending on the account type. I guess I didn't make that clear. Anyway, what interested me most was whether it's wise to define the account type implicitly through the payment plan, so I'll mark this as the accepted answer.