# SQL Foreign Key Redundancy

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, foreign-keys, primary-key

This is a question about foreign key redundancy

[redundant foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773205/redundant-foreign-key)  <- Similar Question

In General:

A *Foreign Key* from **TABLE C** references a *Primary Key* from **Table B**
A *Foreign Key* From **Table C** references a *Primary Key* from **Table A**
A *Foreign Key* from **Table B** references a *Primary Key* from **Table A**

Is the Foreign Key from C -> A necessary since C is connected through B to A?

Specific: 3 tables

### Supplier Info  Table A

Supplier ID - PK

### Person Contact Info (for supplier)  Table B

Part # - PK
Date Received  - PK
Supplier ID - FK

### Part Rprt Table C

Part # - PK & FK
Date - PK & FK
Supplier ID - FK

Thanks - Suggestions for reworking all the table are also welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key would technically be redundant if you assume that the supplier for a person is *always* the supplier represented by the part.  Remember, that things can change over time.  Presumably, suppliers could merge, persons could change the supplier they are associated with, and the supplier associated with a part could change.

The data structure, however, does not look properly normalized.  I would think that you would want a `person` table with information only about the person.  I don't get the relationship between parts and persons.

So, I think you should rework your data structure.  I would suggest that you start with the entities you have identified -- suppliers, persons, and parts.  Then create association tables for them, if necessary.  It is quite possible that each person should just have a `SupplierId` and each part should have a `SupplierId` and that models the relationships.  If there is a relationship between parts and persons, then you might be able to satisfy that with just a `PersonId` field in parts.